# How to hide previous data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im doing some basic programming of Javascript and jquery.. Please run the snippet first to see the output.(cant post image :()

When i click 'saga' it append the information of saga.. later, if i click persona it append persona below of the existed data. I want it to be like this-When i click persona the previous data will vanish and replaced with new one.

my code:

Javascript

```js
function myCar(carName, carPlate, carColor) {
    this.carName = carName;
    this.carPlate = carPlate;
    this.carColor = carColor;
};

var Saga = new myCar('Saga', 'BLM2222', 'blue'),
    Persona = new myCar('Persona', 'JKQ2390', 'red'),
    Wira = new myCar('Wira','GVB3450','violet');

myCar.prototype.details = function($div){
    $div.append('Car Name: ' + this.carName + '<br>' + 'Car Plate: ' + this.carPlate + '<br>' + 'Car Color:' + this.carColor + '<br>' + '<br>');
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cars').click(function(e) {
        var cars = $(e.target);

        switch(cars[0].id) {
            case 'sagabtn':
                Saga.details($('#bigdiv'));
                break;
            case 'sonabtn':
                Persona.details($('#bigdiv'));
                break;
            case 'wirabtn':
                Wira.details($('#bigdiv'));
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Proton</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>-->
</head>
<body>
<h1>Proton Cars</h1>
<div id="cars">
    <button id="sagabtn">Saga</button>
    <br><br>
    <button id="sonabtn">Persona</button>
    <br><br>
    <button id="wirabtn">Wira</button>
    <br><br>
</div>
<div id="bigdiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.append` you can use `.html`. `.append` will add to the DOM. `.html` will replace the html.

Read these articles: http://api.jquery.com/html/ http://api.jquery.com/append/

```js
function myCar(carName, carPlate, carColor) {
    this.carName = carName;
    this.carPlate = carPlate;
    this.carColor = carColor;
};

var Saga = new myCar('Saga', 'BLM2222', 'blue'),
    Persona = new myCar('Persona', 'JKQ2390', 'red'),
    Wira = new myCar('Wira','GVB3450','violet');

myCar.prototype.details = function($div){
    $div.html('Car Name: ' + this.carName + '<br>' + 'Car Plate: ' + this.carPlate + '<br>' + 'Car Color:' + this.carColor + '<br>' + '<br>');
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cars').click(function(e) {
        var cars = $(e.target);

        switch(cars[0].id) {
            case 'sagabtn':
                Saga.details($('#bigdiv'));
                break;
            case 'sonabtn':
                Persona.details($('#bigdiv'));
                break;
            case 'wirabtn':
                Wira.details($('#bigdiv'));
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Proton</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>-->
</head>
<body>
<h1>Proton Cars</h1>
<div id="cars">
    <button id="sagabtn">Saga</button>
    <br><br>
    <button id="sonabtn">Persona</button>
    <br><br>
    <button id="wirabtn">Wira</button>
    <br><br>
</div>
<div id="bigdiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Solved!.. Thanks alot dude.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `document.getElementById("bigdiv").textContent = "";`  to clear on each button press